# How to use 都 and 也 together？

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure

How can I use 都 and 也 together？

For example if I want to say;

> Both of us also think that you like her.

How will I go about it?
I know you can say (colloquially) 俩 but you still need 都 afterwords. Not to mention 都 also goes infront of 大家， 每天 etc.

Can I just go with;

> 我们俩都也觉得你喜欢她。

I have a feeling it's incorrect but just throwing my thought process out there

I'm aware that there is a [grammar rule](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22ye%22_and_%22dou%22_together) to use both of these words but this is for similarities between multiple statements. I want to know how (if it's possible) to use them in a single statement like the one abovementioned.

More sentences:

A: I think you should leave.

B: The both of us also think you should leave.

And,

A: I hate him.

B: Everyone hates him too.

How will I say these sentences (and more like these) if I were person B?

Comment: 我们俩也都觉得你喜欢她。也 precedes 都

Comment: @TooskyHierot So I can use them together? But I have to make sure 也 always precedes 都? So would 大家也都喜欢电影。 Be correct? (because it sounds pretty odd to me. But then again I'm a beginner)

Comment: Yes. (●°u°●)​ 」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice to put 也 and 都 together.

我们俩也都觉得你喜欢她 might be ok, but 我们俩也觉得你喜欢她 or 我们俩都觉得你喜欢她 sounds more natural.

我们俩也觉得你喜欢她 and 我们俩都觉得你喜欢她 have slightly different meanings. 我们俩也觉得你喜欢她 implies that there are someone else already thinking you like her and we also think so. 我们俩都觉得你喜欢她 just means both of us think you like her.